# Getting all uiviewcontrollers which are loaded

Tags: ios, debugging, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

I want to print a list of all of the app's viewcontrollers which are loaded in order to understand why am I getting a white screen and for general debugging purposes.

Please advise,
Thanks,
Asaf

Comment: is it coming with a white screen?

Answer (score 1):

You can do some recursive printout like this (I know it's not perfect, but it's a start):

```
static void printViewControllerRecursively(UIViewController *viewController, NSUInteger level)
{
    NSMutableString *spaces = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:level * 3];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < level; ++i)
    {
        [spaces appendString:@"   "];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@->%@", spaces, viewController);

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]])
    {
        for (UIViewController *child in [(UITabBarController *)viewController viewControllers])
        {
            printViewControllerRecursively(child, level + 1);
        }
    }
    else if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        for (UIViewController *child in [(UINavigationController *)viewController viewControllers])
        {
            printViewControllerRecursively(child, ++level);
        }
    }
}
```

Then just call `printViewControllerRecursively([UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a good way to try and debug anyhitng but that being said you can use:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.navigationController viewControllers]);
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.tabBarController viewControllers]);
```

etc ...

Guess it depends on how you've setup your App.